# bash: when using output from cat of multiple files, can I indicate how many were opened/specify what content belongs to which?

Tags: bash, pipe

When I do `cat *.txt | ./myscript.sh` and then in myscript.sh I save the piped output to a variable, is it possible to somehow find out which content belongs to which file, respectively which files have been opened, like is there some background information cat produces that isn't directly visible in the output? Or is the output I see directly the only thing I can work with.

Comment: @Aaron: Actually I think chepner was writing his own "terrible answer" as a comment... not directed toward you.

Comment: @l'L'l oh, right, this is better for my feelings :) Still, my answer was incorrect aside from its last part, which I don't think is worth more than a comment

Comment: Here is a terrible answer: your script can a) muck around with lsof to determine which process is writing to the other end of the pipe it is reading from, b) use lsof again to figure out which files that command is reading from, and then c) read those files itself. If you are going to that much trouble, though, you should be taking Aaron's advice and taking filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without going through much more trouble than it's worth : `cat` will produce the content of the file on its standard output, which your script will receive on its standard input. From the perspective of your script, it's the same as if you did an `echo` of the content of the file, and the only "file" you could reference is the standard input of your script.

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) mentions you could rely on `lsof` to retrieve the process that was the source of the data, and from there retrieve the file, but the usual way to solve this would be to change your script so that it accepts files as parameters and handle itself reading their content.

You would then invoke `./myscript.sh *.txt`, which would be expanded by `bash` to `./myscript.sh file1.txt file2.txt ...`, and your script could simply call `cat $@` to retrieve the same data, while still having the possibility to retrieve the list of filenames.

Comment: I'm aware this is a better practice, I just wondered if there's a (nice) way doing so with piped `cat`, thanks for the clarification.